# Matlab log(1) is not always zero

Tags: matlab

I am developing an image processing application for object detection.

At some point I am using log of the generalized eigenvalues vector of two square covariance matrices.
Assume that I have a 9x9 covariance matrix a.

```
a = rand(9, 9)%just generating random matrix for testing problem easily

b = eig(a, a)%generalized eigenvalues vector containing nine values equal to 1
             %so we have b = [1.000, 1.000, 1.000 ... (9 times)]

c = log(b(:)) %we know b contains values of 1. and log(1) is 0.
```

Even though we know and can debug to see that b contains elements with value 1 and log(1) is 0, content of c is:

```
1.0e-014 *

0.0222
0.1110
0.0222
0.0222
-0.0777
0
0.0222
0.0888
0
```

This in my case.
Anyone knows why doesn't c have values of 0?
Thanks.

Comment: Probably because the values in your `b` array are not exactly equal to 1.

Comment: I agree with Oli. Just perform a (b-1) and you'll see that they're not all 0's.

Comment: `1e-15` is zero in most contexts you can use http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20029-zero-out-smalls/content/zero_out_smalls/zero_out_smalls.m if you work in planck's order of magnitude

Comment: read What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @OliCharlesworth commented the values of b aren't really 1.  I did the exact same as you did and got the following for b:

```
b =

    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
    1.0000
```

But when I opened b up in the variable explorer I got the following:

[image: Ya only one true one]

You'll see that there's only really one value of `1` and not `1.000` meaning that there are some trailing values that aren't shown in MatLab.  Hence you would get the following for c:

```
c =

   1.0e-15 *

    0.2220
   -0.4441
    0.2220
   -0.2220
    0.2220
         0
    0.2220
   -0.1110
   -0.1110
```

Notice the `1.0e-15` that's where trailing values are being found.

Answer (score 1):

Trailing zeros after a number, like

> 1.0000

indicates, that it is not exactly this value.
Try

> format long

to see trailing digits up to 15.
If this isn't exactly enough, try out the print command

> sprintf('%.50f',b(1))

to see 50 trailing digits of the value b(1).

Thus, the numbers are not exactly 1, neither log becomes exactly 0.